# How to store the variable returned from a closure function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Noticed the code of the `submitHandler` was being used in several places, and tried to refactor it out.

```
var validator = $("#form_id").validate({
            errorClass: "ui-state-error",
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(entity) {
                        //dostuff
                    },
                    error: function(errors) {
                            validator.showErrors(errors);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

I took the code above and extracted the submithandler to a function like so;

```
$("#generated_form_id").validate({
                errorClass: "ui-state-error",
                submitHandler: bindSubmitHandler(formId)
                }
            });

    function bindSubmitHandler(formId){
            return function(form) {
                    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(object) {
                            //do stuff
                            });
                        },
                        error: function(errors) {
                                validator.showErrors(errors); //throws an exception
                        }
                    });
                }
        }
```

This code throws an exception because the validator object is undefined.

*My own reasoning* which may be false has been as follows: I can't store the variable, because the forms are being created dynamically. One page could create ten of these forms using the same `bindSubmitHandler` function. 
I thought about the solution of getting the validator via the form, but couldn't find any such method in the validator API. If there is such a method, I could write something like `$('#formid').getValidator().showErrors(errors);`

**Does anyone have an idea for a solution to this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validate()` returns a validator.

Attach the validator to the form using `.data()`, retrieve it `bindSubmitHandler`.

Wouldn't you also want to pass in `success` and possibly `error` handlers as well, though?

Comment: Ahh, great solution! Yes I'll prob. add that aswell, just wasn't needed at this point.